# javascript JSON and Array elements, help me understand the rule about quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, quotes

When using a returned value to determine the number of an element in an array, does javascript throw quotes around it?

Example :

This tallys the number of times unique characters are used.

```
var uniques = {};

function charFreq(s)
{ 
    for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
       if(isNaN(uniques[s.charAt(i)])) uniques[s.charAt(i)] = 1;
       else uniques[s.charAt(i)] = uniques[s.charAt(i)] + 1;
    }

    return uniques;    
}

console.log(charFreq("ahasdsadhaeytyeyeyehahahdahsdhadhahhhhhhhhhha"));
```

It just seems funny that uniques[s.charAt(i)] works, and uniques[a] wont work (due to lack of quotes). uniques[a] will get you a nasty 'a is undefined'.

Comment: That's a bit of an abuse of `isNaN` there. It would be clearer to say: `var c= s.charAt(i); if (!(c in uniques)) uniques[c]= 0; uniques[c]++;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a JavaScript object using the `[]` notation, you are using a **string** as a key in the object.  You can also address properties using the `.` notation:

`uniques.a` is the same as `uniques['a']`

The reason you aren't adding quotes to the `s.charAt(i)` is that it returns a **string**, which is then used as the property to check on the `uniques` object.

`uniques[a]` will create an error, because no **variable** with the name `a` has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version -- `uniques[s.charAt(i)]` -- you're doing the lookup using an *expression*. JavaScript evaluates the expression -- `s.charAt(i)` -- and uses the evaluated value (maybe `a`) to perform the lookup in the `uniques` map.

In the second version -- `uniques[a]` -- you want to do the lookup using the *literal* character `a`, but unless you wrap it in quotes then JavaScript treats the `a` as an expression rather than a literal. When it tries to evaluate the "expression" then you get an error.

So the rule is: character/string literals need quotes; expressions that evaluate to characters/strings don't.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Javascript evaluates the expression between [] like `uniques[s.charAt(i)]` which is of the type *MemberExpression[ Expression ]* :

1. Let *propertyNameReference* be the result of evaluating Expression.
2. Let *propertyNameValue* be *GetValue(propertyNameReference)*.
3. Let *propertyNameString* be ***ToString(propertyNameValue)***.

So in the 3rd step it is converting the property name into a string.